# Making a nursery rhyme for kids

Tags: music, youtube

not sure if this is the right stack site to ask this. I have a channel for kids in a non English country. We want to make a song ourselves for a video and we need an instrumental to sing the song with. I am wondering if we are allowed to download an instrumental from one of the royalty free sites and use it for making the song. Note that the song would be used only in that one video.

Also, I saw that there are instrumentals being sold on Amazon, can we use these?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a better fit for the Law stack. As in, “how does royalty free music work?”

Answer (score 0):

If it is only for personal use, then you should be fine. If you are thinking of any commercial application, you need to be au-fait with the licensing restrictions around any audio you access and use. This will differ depending on the audio source and you need to be very clear on what these licenses allow you to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different parts to a music licensing agreement.

The first part is whether or not you can reproduce the original work. This simply means whether you're allowed to copy it or not. This is usually all that these "royalty-free" sites deal with.

The second part is more tricky and deals with whether or not you can publish the work and what credits you need to share when you do publish it. The "royalty-free" sites will generally tell you what you're allowed to do with the work but not how to negotiate changes.

EDIT:

I forgot to add that the rights to the composition and the rights to the recording are two different things. You can have either or both. If you have the rights to the recording you may make copies of the recording but not re-record your won version. If you have rights to the composition then you can make new recordings but not reproduce existing recordings.

TL;DR read the fine print.